# Does marginal likelihood have closed-form solution for hyperparameters in Bayesian linear regression?

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, optimization, linear-model, gaussian-process

We know that marginal likelihood has the following form in Bayesian linear regression,
$$
\mathbf{K} = \sigma_w^2XX^T + \sigma_n^2I\\
p(\mathbf{y}|X) \sim \mathcal{N}(0, K)\\
\log p(\mathbf{y}|X) =
  -\frac{1}{2} \mathbf{y}^{T}
                K^{-1}
               \mathbf{y}
  - \frac{1}{2}\log|K|
  - \frac{n}{2}\log (2 \pi)
$$

Can we estimate $\sigma_n$ and $\sigma_w$ in closed form by maximizing log marginal likelihood or with any other way (other than numerical methods such as gradient descent)? I am also interested to know if this is possible for Gaussian process regression where $K$ could be RBF or Matern or any other kernel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This blog post](http://krasserm.github.io/2019/02/23/bayesian-linear-regression/) gives the answer I was looking for. There is a method to estimate $\sigma_w$ and $\sigma_n$ parameters for linear regression that is computationally far better than fitting a GP with linear kernel.

Answer (score 1):

That is the exact procedure used in GP. Kernel parameters obtained by maximizing log marginal likelihood. You can use any numerical opt. method you want to obtain kernel parameters, they all have their advantages and disadvantages. I dont think there is closed form solution for parameters though.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your answer. I could relate it to GP that way but intuitively thought that linear regression being the simplest model may have some trick.